# view access permission

Tags: 7, views, users

I have a problem with view permission, when I make a view in drupal 7 there is an option "access" when I specify the option eg:"view published content" all users that has the role of published content can see all the content that are belongs to that view. But I want some thing else, I want to give the permission for users to access just his/her own published content not all published content that are belongs to that view.
cheers

Comment: You want this only for views or outside views also ?

Comment: @sandeshyadav OP mentioned only for view

Answer (score 0):

You can add a contextual filter "Content: Author uid" which defaults to "User ID from logged in user". Or you could also try to add a relationship to the author of the content and compare it's uid to the uid of the logged in user.